# How to check wifi connectivity lost in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, android-broadcast, connectivity

i have 2 devices that are in same wifi network and are connected. Now, i want to listen whenever the device gets disconnected or reconnects. I dont want to listen to wifi connectivity with device but the connectivity between 2 devices in same wifi network.
How can we do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its certainly possible by using [Android's peer to peer connection](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html).

This is from the above link.

> The WifiP2pManager.ActionListener implemented in this snippet only
>   notifies you when the initiation succeeds or fails. To listen for
>   changes in connection state, implement the
>   WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener interface. Its
>   onConnectionInfoAvailable() callback will notify you when the state of
>   the connection changes. In cases where multiple devices are going to
>   be connected to a single device (like a game with 3 or more players,
>   or a chat app), one device will be designated the "group owner".

Answer (score 1):

We can communicate between 2 phones in the same using regular Socket's.

[Server Side Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html)
[Client Side Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

If you have a large amount of data to transfer, internet sockets have a greater data capacity and will be faster. The other advantage is that there is no such thing as "out of range". You can connect the two devices wherever internet is available.

So a UDP broadcast would seem like a good option. I.e where 2 devices with same app are running and a packet is broadcasted from one device on a particular socket, where as the other side the app listens on that socket.